# NDK <Utils/Log.h> no such file or directory

Tags: java, android, c++, eclipse, android-ndk

Ok so I want to compile an FM Radio app i picked up on [Github](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_packages_apps_FMRadio), I have never tried making a Low level language app before this is my first attempt, so I though of first compiling an already working project and analysing it, Android studio asked me to download ND set it up afterwards I developed this error:`Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugNdk'.

> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>       /Applications/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/ndk/ndk-build NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=/********************/********************/AndroidStudioProjects/android_packages_apps_FMRadio-cm-12.1/app/build/intermediates/ndk/debug/Android.mk APP_PLATFORM=android-21 NDK_OUT=/********************/********************/AndroidStudioProjects/android_packages_apps_FMRadio-cm-12.1/app/build/intermediates/ndk/debug/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=/********************/********************/AndroidStudioProjects/android_packages_apps_FMRadio-cm-12.1/app/build/intermediates/ndk/debug/lib APP_ABI=all
>     Error Code:
>       2
>     Output:
>       In file included from /********************/********************/********************/android_packages_apps_FMRadio-cm-12.1/app/src/main/jni/fmr/common.cpp:17:0:
>       /********************/********************/AndroidStudioProjects/android_packages_apps_FMRadio-cm-12.1/app/src/main/jni/fmr/fmr.h:21:23: fatal error: utils/Log.h: No such file or directory
>        #include 
>                              ^
>       compilation terminated.
>       make: *** [/********************/********************/AndroidStudioProjects/android_packages_apps_FMRadio-cm-12.1/app/build/intermediates/ndk/debug/obj/local/arm64-v8a/objs/app//********************/********************/AndroidStudioProjects/android_packages_apps_FMRadio-cm-12.1/app/src/main/jni/fmr/common.o] Error 1`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like that project is not meant to be build as a standalone app, but as part of a full firmware build (part of Cyanogen Mod). The error basically says the file `utils/log.h` could not be found. That file is not part of this project and it is not part of the Android NDK.

To avoid having to setup a complete environment you are most likely not going to use, i suggest picking another project to start with.

If you ***REALLY*** want to stick with this project, i suggest you start with some changes in the file `jni/fmr/fmr.h`

1: Change `<utils/log.h>` into `<android/log.h>`.

When you recompile, it will probably complain about all the ALOG* defines it cannot find.

2: Replace this part:

```
#undef FM_LIB_USE_XLOG

#ifdef FM_LIB_USE_XLOG
#include <cutils/xlog.h>
#undef LOGV
#define LOGV(...) XLOGV(__VA_ARGS__)
#undef LOGD
#define LOGD(...) XLOGD(__VA_ARGS__)
#undef LOGI
#define LOGI(...) XLOGI(__VA_ARGS__)
#undef LOGW
#define LOGW(...) XLOGW(__VA_ARGS__)
#undef LOGE
#define LOGE(...) XLOGE(__VA_ARGS__)
#else
#undef LOGV
#define LOGV(...) ALOGV(__VA_ARGS__)
#undef LOGD
#define LOGD(...) ALOGD(__VA_ARGS__)
#undef LOGI
#define LOGI(...) ALOGI(__VA_ARGS__)
#undef LOGW
#define LOGW(...) ALOGW(__VA_ARGS__)
#undef LOGE
#define LOGE(...) ALOGE(__VA_ARGS__)
#endif
```

with this part:

```
#define LOGV(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE,LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)
#define LOGD(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG,LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)
#define LOGI(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO,LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)
#define LOGW(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_WARN,LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)
#define LOGE(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR,LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)
```

That should get you started.

edit:

I think i found the referenced `utils/log.h` (but maybe not from the correct project):
https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_frameworks_ex/blob/cm-12.0/framesequence/jni/utils/log.h

Comment: Thank you very much, it did not work but you were very helpful.